# Por quê não podemos preceder um toponímio feminino com o artigo feminino?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, gênero

Eu estava a tentar perceber intuitivamente qual é o gênero do nome de algumas cidades. Por exemplo, para o masculino é fácil:

> O Porto.

Percebemos imediatamente pelo gênero do artigo que *Porto* é substantivo masculino.

---

Mas para o feminino é mais difícil construir uma frase, o seguinte exemplo não é gramatical:

> A Lisboa. A Coimbra. A Braga.

Em vez disso teriamos de escrever:

> A cidade de Lisboa, Coimbra, Braga...

O que não é tão simples como dizer *"A Lisboa"* equivalente a *"O Porto"*. Alguém consegue explicar isto? Eu também acho que a frase exemplo *"A cidade de..."* talvez não seja a melhor para perceber o gênero do substantivo, alguém sabe exemplos de frases que tornem o gênero do substantivo mais evidente?

Comment: Após pensar nisto mais um bocado começo a ter a impressão que em português os nomes de cidades são maioritariamente de género neutro, por vezes femininos e raramente masculinos. São masculinos só quando o toponímio coincide com o nome de um objecto masculino como Porto ou Cabo...

Comment: A premissa não está correta. Se se usa o artigo ou não não tem que ver com o género do nome. _Vou à Arrentela/Amora/Charneca da Caparica. Mas vou a Lisboa/Almada/Alhandra/Vila Franca de Xira_. _Lisboa/Almada/Alhandra/VFX é bonita_. O mesmo para o masculino: _o Porto é bonito_, mas _Azeitão é bonito_.

Comment: @Artefacto bons exemplos, acho que as primeiras 3 cidades são femininas (por isso usas o artigo com contração) enquanto o segundo conjunto de 3 é de género neutro, por isso usas o artigo sem contração. Nas últimas duas o Porto é masculino mas acho que Azeitão é de género neutro.

Comment: No RS (Sul do Brasil) existe uma cidade chamada "Feliz" e é costume na região usar o arttigo definido feminino sempre ao invés de apenas a preposição: "eu estudo _na_ Feliz", "eu gostei muito _da_ Feliz". Diz a lenda que se não fosse assim teríamos um cacófato "eu estudo em Feliz" --> "eu estudo infeliz". Fora este exemplo, todos outros que eu consigo pensar se aplcam à cidades brasileiras. "Eu nasci em Brasília", mas "eu nasci no Rio de Janeiro".

Comment: @gmauch obrigado pelos exemplos, eu continuo sem encontrar uma explicação formal para estes casos nas gramáticas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A razão pela qual não podemos usar o artigo feminino antes de um toponímio feminino é simplesmente porque não é gramaticalmente correto em português. Essa é uma regra gramatical estabelecida que deve ser seguida para evitar erros de concordância.

No caso dos exemplos que você mencionou, o correto é dizer "Lisboa", "Coimbra" e "Braga", sem o artigo definido feminino "A". Dessa forma, esses nomes de cidades são considerados substantivos femininos.

Uma maneira de tornar o gênero do substantivo mais evidente é usando um adjetivo concordante em gênero antes do substantivo, nesse caso é possível sim utilizar o artigo. Por exemplo:

A bela Lisboa.  A antiga Coimbra.  A querida Braga.

Nesses casos, o adjetivo concorda em gênero com o substantivo feminino, deixando claro que se trata de um substantivo feminino. Pelo mesmo motivo, usa-se "O Porto", já que existem muitos portos, e aquele especificamente é um porto qualificado que o torna único, assim "O Porto".

Também é possível usar uma construção como "a cidade de" seguida do nome da cidade, mas isso não é necessário para estabelecer o gênero do substantivo. A construção "a cidade de" é uma maneira mais formal de se referir a uma cidade, mas não é obrigatória para estabelecer o gênero do substantivo.